# Angular test errors: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: node.js, angular, postcss

Currently getting this error when I run `npx ng test`

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in /home/ecarroll/cp/js/angular-ui/node_modules/postcss/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:416:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:669:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ecarroll/cp/js/angular-ui/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:16:39)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in [PostCSS that was fixed here](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/commit/8e6088f99ca8ae92f70d5207a8478cd22e6ec420). I discovered this fix by [opening up the `package.json` in GitHub](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/main/package.json) and [then using web interface to `git blame` to figure out when the line was added for the `export`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blame/main/package.json#L40)

The fix was rolled out to these versions

```
8.3.11  8.3.10 8.3.9 8.3.8 8.3.7 8.3.6 8.3.5 8.3.4 8.3.3 8.3.2 8.3.1 8.3.0 8.2.15 8.2.14 8.2.13 8.2.12
```

Open up your `package.json`

```
/home/ecarroll/cp/js/angular-ui/node_modules/postcss/package.json
```

take the version number and manually upgrade to the closest one with the fix, so to solve it try

```
npm install postcss@8.2.15
```

Comment: I started getting this error recently. I've been building my Angular app inside a Docker container. The Dockerfile specified `alpine:latest` for building. Switching to an older version (3.15.5) fixed the issue, revealing a deprecation warning in the postcss package. I assume this "fix" really addresses this deprecation.